# Spring Batch - One or more ItemWriter among a list

Tags: java, spring-batch

What I want to do is use one or more `ItemWriter` for a single step, depending on the batch configuration.

What I need is a behaviour between a classic `CompositeItemWriter` (which calls **all** writers) and a classic `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` (which calls **only one** writer); this behaviour would let me call **one or more** writer, with an external condition for each of the writers specified as delegates.

One of the solution I thought about is using a `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` which contains as delegates the list of all possible combination of my writers.
To create combinations of writers, I'd need to declare as many `CompositeItemWriter` as needed (2<sup>n</sup> - (n + 1), where `n` is the total number of "real" writers). Then the `Classifier` would be custom-made to return a code formatted as a bit-word with each bit is the statuts of a writer (activation could depend on properties configuration or jobParameters, etc.)

Here's an example with 2 writers :

```
<bean class="ClassifierCompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="matcherMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="10">
                <bean ref="writer1" />
            </entry>
            <entry key="01">
                <bean ref="writer2" />
            </entry>
            <entry key="11">
                <bean ref="writer1and2" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="writer1" />
<bean id="writer2" />

<bean id="writer1and2" class="CompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="delegates">
        <bean ref="writer1" />
        <bean red="writer2" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

This solution is actually working but requires a great number of `CompositeItemReader` as the number of "real" writers grows.

Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Take the `CompositeItemWriter` out of the mix. Create your own `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` which takes per classifier a list of `ItemWriter`s instead of a single one, then iterate.

Comment: @M.Deinum The `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` isn't the one managing the list of writers, it is actually the `Classifier` who would need to return a list of `ItemWriter` instead of a single one. So I can't really implement a custom `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` without changing the core classify mechanic.

Comment: Yes you can just implement it yourself... I nowhere said you should modify the existing one... Also looking at the code you would only need to create your own `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` . The `Classifier` is generic and can happily take a collection of `ItemWriter`s.