# Spring batch - ItemWriter different operations based on a condition

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have to do a batch process that reads from a DB table, check a rather convoluted bunch of conditions and, depending on those, do some operation in another table.

"Some operation" can mean:

- A stored procedure call.
- A stored procedure plus an update.
- A series of updates and another stored procedure call.

What are my options?

Use a ClassifierCompositeItemWriter + several CompositeItemWriters like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180075/spring-batch-one-or-more-itemwriter-among-a-list)?
Go with a custom ItemWriter? Or something else that I've failed to see?

Also, in this context, would batching (as in, using JdbcBatchItemWriter) help? I mean if it would finish faster.

Comment: I suppose ClassifierCompositeItemWriter + CompositeItemWriters can be enough. For updates you can use JdbcBatchItemWriter as delegate in your composite item writer